# Setup an apache Virtual Hosts on Debian 7

Tags: apache, debian, virtualhost

I tried to setup an apache virtual host on a fresh debian 7 installation like following:

#### applied steps

1.Install apache server:

```
apt-get install apache2
```

2.create my new derictory:

```
mkdir -p /var/www/newsite.com/httpdocs
```

3.give the required permissions to the virtual host

```
chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/newsite.com/httpdocs

chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

4.create a simple index file to test the results:

```
nano /var/www/newsite.com/httpdocs/index.html
```

5.enable the site:

```
   cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-available/newsite.com
```

open the new config file to edit it:

```
nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/newsite.com
```

add ServerName,ServerAlias and DocumentRoot:

```
ServerName newsite.com
ServerAlias www.newsite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/newsite.com/httpdocs
```

activate the host:

```
a2ensite newsite.com
```

and then restart apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```

#### obtained result

I can now access my index file through the web browser but only when I type:

```
Server_IP/newsite.com/httpdocs
```

#### Question

I want to access my virtual host directly by typing newsite.com in my web browser, what step is missing to achieve this and itis possible to point to a specific file(index.html or index.php )as a default starting file for the virtual host?

#### EDIT:

content of config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName newsite.com
        ServerAlias www.newsite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/newsite.com/httpdocs
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Which version of apache2 are you running? 2.2 or 2.4?

Comment: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian).. actually I tried too via Parallels Plesk Panel and added a new domain newsite2.com upload the required data and then once I checked enabled-sites my newsite2.com was enabled automatically but when I type the newsite2.com in the browser the default  Parallels Plesk Panel page is displayed

Answer (score 0):

Few things you need to consider here:

1. If you're trying to access newsite.com, you need to make sure there is an appropriate DNS record, or add the domain and IP to your hosts file.
2. Your `<Directory>` tag should be `<Directory /var/www/newsite.com/httpdocs>`
3. Make sure you have `NameVirtualHost *:80` in your apache config somewhere, this would normally go in `ports.conf` on Debian. Without this, apache will serve the default virtual host, which it sounds like it's doing as you have to type `newsite.com/httpdocs` to see your content.

Comment: could you please explain the first point:how to make sure of the  appropriate DNS record

Comment: use `nslookup` and type in the domain name for you site. If the IP of your server is returned, you have done this correctly. Otherwise you'll need to add an A record for your domain with your DNS provider.

Comment: I get this `Server:IP
Address:IP#53

** server can't find newsite.com: NXDOMAIN`